# meta fields for the whole wordpress site

Tags: custom-field, options

Is there a simple way to store additional information related to the whole website in a meta field?

For users, comments or posts, I learned how to use meta fields to store their additional related information, but sometimes I need to have growing arrays that contain additional information about the whole website.

Your clarifications are appreciated.

Comment: You can store options for the site using the [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about ["Options"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). These are saved in the `*_options` table and can be stored and retrieved using a number of Core functions (straight from the Codex page above):

**Add/Delete Option**

- [add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option)
- [delete_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_option)
- [add_site_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_site_option)
- [delete_site_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_site_option)

**Get/Update Option**

- [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)
- [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)
- [get_site_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option)
- [update_site_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_site_option)

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields should be used to store additional details assigned to posts/pages.

You should use [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) to store global options.

You should use user meta to store additional user details.

You can also read this: [Best way to present options for home page in admin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103433/best-way-to-present-options-for-home-page-in-admin/103844#103844)

Comment: You and the comment owner are experts pointing me  to Options API, so this is what I will use. Thank you very much.