# How do you create a re-useable HTML fragment in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, themes, cms

Let's say you want all pages to have a common footer, and have that footer  editable in WordPress; how would you accomplish this?

My current solution is to create a page "footer" and include it using custom template function.

But I am wondering if there is a better way to do it, without requiring custom coding.

As an example, in the footer of this page you have the text statement

> "WordPress is a trademark of the WordPress Foundation, registered in
>   the US and other countries. This site is not affiliated with the
>   WordPress Foundation in any way."

How do you make them editable by normal wordpress user?

Comment: Show us what you mean by "include" it.

Comment: Also, what elements are you wanting to edit?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103433/best-way-to-present-options-for-home-page-in-admin/103844#103844

Comment: I would say either Custom Fields or Custom Post Types, probably the former though

Comment: Create a custom footer? `footer-yourspecialfooter.php` and call it in the template that displays pages, ie. `page.php` calls `get_footer('yourspecialfooter');`. No time for full answer, else i'd write one out for you.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, the footer part is shared across different page, so custom field is not preferred.

Comment: @Wyck, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

If this text was static, then of course you could use custom footer template. So create file `footer-my-custom.php` and then include it with `get_footer('footer', 'my-custom');`

If you want to edit this text in wp-admin (or have many editable texts in there) you can use one of these solutions:

### 1. Custom Fields (good if you use static front page)

If you use static front page, then you can add some custom fields to it and then show these fields in footer on every page. To add these CF only to front page, I would use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin.

Then in footer you'll have to add:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_option('page_on_front'), '<CUSTOM FIELD NAME>', true ); ?>
```

### 2. Options

The other solution (better in this case, I guess) is to define some theme options.

I usually use [OptionTree](http://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) plugin to do this. But it's not so hard to do this [by yourself](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest method.

1. Create a fragment php file in your Theme. This file will include all your fragments. We will use a built in PHP technique called [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to make this cleaner.

**fragments.php**

```
function htmlList () {
    return <<<HTML
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
            <li>Ad, unde.</li>
            <li>Explicabo, delectus.</li>
            <li>Hic, dolore.</li>
            <li>Alias, obcaecati!</li>
        </ul>
    HTML;
}
```

2. Now link and call the fragment in your template

```
<?php 
require get_template_directory() . '/fragments.php';
?>

<?php echo $htmlList; ?>
```