# Remove Editor From Homepage

Tags: filters, actions, visual-editor

Im trying to remove the editor from the homepage using the following functions however I am struggling to achieve this?

```
function hide_homepage_editor() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        if (is_front_page()) {
            remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_homepage_editor' );
```

another try:

```
function hide_homepage_editor() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        $post_id = 0;
        if(isset($_GET['post'])) $post_id = $_GET['post'];
        $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', TRUE);
        if ($template_file == 'front-page.php') {
            remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_homepage_editor' );
```

Anyone know why these are not working and how I can remove the page editor from the page set as frontpage?

Comment: You mean in the admin panel when editing a post which is selected as homepage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your approach

By using the **admin_init** hook you won't have any reference to the post object. This means you won't be able to get the post ID or use anything like get_the_ID because the post won't actually be loaded. You can see that in the order here https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

So if you run the action hook after the wp action you'll have the post object. For example

```
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_content_editor');
/**
 * Remove the content editor from ALL pages 
 */
function remove_content_editor()
{ 
    remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');        
}
```

Now this snippet will remove the editor from all pages. The problem is that **is_home** and **is_front_page** won't work on the admin side so you'll need to add some meta data to distinguish whether you're on the home page. There's a very comprehensive discussion of approaches for that on this page: [Best way to present options for home page in admin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103433/best-way-to-present-options-for-home-page-in-admin)

So, if you used some extra meta data, you can then check this like

```
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_content_editor');
/**
 * Remove the content editor from ALL pages 
 */
function remove_content_editor()
{
    //Check against your meta data here
    if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'is_home_page' )){      
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');         
    }

}
```

Hopefully that will help you out

******* Update ************

Actually, I've just looked into this again and realised that there is an easier way.  If you have set the front page to be a static page in the Reading settings, you can check against the **page_on_front** option value. In that case, the following will work

```
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_content_editor');
/**
 * Remove the content editor from pages as all content is handled through Panels
 */
function remove_content_editor()
{
    if((int) get_option('page_on_front')==get_the_ID())
    {
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Your updated example is exactly what I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Update for Wordpress 5 with Gutenberg:

```
<?php
/**
 * Disable standard editor and Gutenberg for the homepage
 * keeping the status (enabled/disabled) for others who uses the same filter (i.e. ACF)
 */
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', 'yourtheme_hide_editor', 10, 2 );
function yourtheme_hide_editor( $use_block_editor, $post_type ) {
    if ( (int) get_option( 'page_on_front' ) == get_the_ID() ) { // on frontpage
        remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' ); // disable standard editor
        return false; // and disable gutenberg
    }

    return $use_block_editor; // keep gutenberg status for other pages/posts 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the solution Andrew. I added a code for the page translated by polylang to apply the filter too:

```
/**
 * Remove the content editor from front page
 */
function remove_content_editor(){
    if((int) get_option('page_on_front')==get_the_ID()){
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
    if(function_exists("pll_get_post")){
        if((int) pll_get_post(get_the_ID(),"en")==get_the_ID()){
            remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_content_editor');
```

Change "en" to the matching language string. in my case first language is german and second english (en).